# Xcode 13 update height UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

tell me how you can fix this behavior in xcode 13, updating the cell height does not work. In xcode 12.5.1 works fine
https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0Wq4Ml4Zl_0Hk4XcQxrQ3FIwg#TableView

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if isHideCell && indexPath.row == 1 {
        return 0
    } else {
        return tableView.rowHeight
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard indexPath.row == 0 else { return }
    isHideCell = !isHideCell
    tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil)
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with **Xcode 13** -- it's an issue with **iOS 15**

Apparently (based on quick testing), `heightForRowAt` treats zero-height rows as "non-visible rows" and so it is ***not*** called for that row if you've set it's height to Zero.

You can try to get around this by setting the row height to `0.01` instead:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if isHideCell && indexPath.row == 1 {
        return 0.01
    }
    return tableView.rowHeight
}
```